# PHP design questions

Tags: php

I am new to PHP language, I've got some questions which seems hard to understand for me.

comparing with other programming language, such as python or Java, PHP has too-many built-in functions which are available without "import" or "require" it,
    how the PHP interpreter do this? If it loaded all the functions when launching, it seems it will be much slower as it will try to load the libraries into memory.

I will try to show some code in python. Here is the python library list
https://docs.python.org/2/library/

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()

import os
import string
import re

end = datetime.datetime.now()

print (end - start).microseconds / float(pow(10, 6))
```

output is 
0.004, so it will takes about 0.004 seconds to load just 3 modules, not all, I guess it will be more than 1 seconds if load all built-in libraries into memory using python.
I don't believe PHP will load the low level libraries faster than python, so when does PHP loads the built-in functions into memory? As usually, the apache will launch a PHP interpreter process to serve the request.

Comment: You only import, include require only the programs that you need. like require codes from another page.

Comment: Yes, built-in functions, those that are part of core PHP, are loaded when launching PHP..... and funnily enough, it isn't much slower, perhaps because the core PHP developers are really quite clever people

Comment: @MarkBaker so it is impossible to create a function which has the same name and variable list as the built-in function, as it will be conflicted?

Comment: Not completely impossible, though that's a completely different question to your original.... the easiest way is to use namespacing, but there are also a couple of extensions (for older versions of PHP) that allow you to manipulate the built-in functions

Comment: PHP loads all those "built-in" functions when you run PHP; whether command line or mod_apache or fpm, or however you load PHP.... in addition to the actual core functions, it will also load in all the libraries that are defined in php.ini as part of that startup process...... and yes, it really does work, seemingly no matter how much you want to disbelieve it

Comment: imo and simplified: Please be aware that operating system decides when memory (executables) get flushed - not the webserver or PHP. So, once the executable that is PHP is loaded and active. When you run a PHP script - the `operating system` decides where it is and what is needed to be done to run your script. For a 'busy PHP system' - it 'throws' your script at the interepreter that already exists in memory.